# How to add class to img in iframe?

Tags: jquery

I wanna add class to img in iframe, how to achieve? thanks

```
   $(iframe).ready(function(){
   $('img[src*="img/logo25.png"]').addClass('selected');
 });
<iframe src="img/logo25.png">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Do you want this <iframe src="img/logo25.png" class="selected"> </iframe> or this <iframe> <img src="img/logo25.png" class="selected" /> </iframe>

Comment: i wanna <iframe> <img src="img/logo25.png" class="selected" /> </iframe>.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do:

```
$('#yourIframeId').contents().find('img[src*="img/logo25.png"]').addClass('selected');
```